# YouTube V3 uploaded Video list by channel id

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube-data-api

In YouTube V2 this works
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCR72FMPr2lMA2mZNOWXUpwg/uploads?orderby=updated&max-results=2&v=2&alt=jsonc

but in youtube v3  i am 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=id,snippet,contentDetails&channelId=UCHgNsDiNvtT966PPFQrF4Ww&maxResults=5&key=AIzaSyDOkg-u9jnhP-WnzX5WPJyV1sc5QQrtuyc
But in result some show video id another way
contentDetails->playlistItem->resourceId->videoId:"eTsw5rry3b8"

contentDetails->upload"->videoId: "eTsw5rry3b8"

In youtube v3 i unable to get video id in v3

Comment: Your question is very confusing. I'm not sure exactly what it is you're needing help with? Perhaps post some code?

Comment: i want youtube v3   api  upload video list by channel id

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following should work for you.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=[THE_CHANNEL_ID]&key=[apiKey]
```

You can put multiple ID's separated by coma's if you required that as well.

As for legacy names, this will work as long as you know it.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=[USER_Name]&key=[apiKey]
```

The uploaded list is here
[contentDetails] => [relatedPlaylists] => [uploads]

Hope that is what you were looking for.